# Is it Possible to use a group inside test

Tags: testng

I have a scenario where i want to use 2 different value for 2 different groups in the same test.

Like let say

```
@Test(groups = ["Abc", "Def"])
void testPqr() {
    int i

    // Is there a way to do something like below in TestNG
    if (@groups ="abc") {
        i=10
    }

    if {@groups ="Def"} {
        i=15
    }
}
```

Is it Possible to use a group inside test?

Answer (score 0):

**Groups** are **labels** of the test and are used to filter what tests/classes you want to run.

What you can do, it using [a test parameter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml) and having 2 test nodes with [group activation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups):

```
@Parameters({ "i" })
@Test(groups = ["Abc", "Def"])
void testPqr(String iValue) {
  int i = Integer.valueOf(iValue);
  ...
}
```

With `testng.xml`:

```
<suite name="My suite">
  <test name="ABS test">
    <parameter name="i" value="10"/>
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="Abc"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      ...
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="DEF test">
    <parameter name="i" value="15"/>
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="Def"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      ...
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```